# use dict from CSV to format dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of Pandas DFs with differing format that should get reshaped into a common target-format.

Right now, I write dictionaries for each DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"original_name":["a","b","c"],"original_value":[1,2,3]})


key_dict = {
  "name":df1.original_name,
  "value":df1.original_value,
  "other_value":np.nan
}

target_colnames = ["name","value","other_value"]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(key_dict, columns = target_colnames)
```

My Problem: The mapping of orginal to target columns with `key_dict` is stored in a CSV file (index= values, columns = key for each DF).

```
key_df= pd.read_csv("key_df.csv").set_index("key")
key_df= key_df.to_dict()

new_df = pd.DataFrame(key_df["df1"], columns = target_colnames)
```

This leads to the following error:

```
 "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"
```

I think it's because the values of 'key_df' are strings unlike in 'key_dict'. Do I need to apply 'eval' on the keys?

this is how 'key_df["df1"]' looks:

```
{'name': 'df1.original_name',
 'other_value': 'np.nan',
 'value': 'df1.original_value'}
```

Comment: Using `key_df["df1"]` doesn't make sense here. You have to use the original code for `new_df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
key_df = {i:eval(j) for i,j in key_df.items()} # Use iteritems() for python 2
new_df = pd.DataFrame(key_dict, columns = target_colnames)
```

**Output**

```
name    value   other_value
a   1   NaN
b   2   NaN
c   3   NaN
```

**Explanation**

After loading and converting to `csv` to `dict`, you have to do a `dict` comprehension to convert the `pd.Series()` values stored as `str` to `eval()` so you can reuse the same `new_df` code to get what you want